# como puedo hacer que prolog busque todos los resultados posibles para mi regla?

Tags: prolog, lógica, swi-prolog

Digamos que quiero crear una regla que me diga los números que existen del 1 al 3...
Yo cree esta regla:

`x(N,R) :- number(N), R =< N, R >= 1.`

y si le pregunto con los 2 argumentos, me responde lo que quiero:

`x(3,4) = false` o
`x(4,1) = true`

pero si pregunto con un solo argumento:

`x(X,6)` o `x(6,X)`

me responde:

```
Arguments are not sufficiently instantiated
In:
   [3] _1418=<3
   [2] x(3,_1474) at  line xx
   [1] '<meta-call>'((trace,...)) <foreign>
```

y no se como decirle que si le pregunto por ejemplo:

x(3,X)

quiero que me diga:

```
X = 2;
X = 3;
false.
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Los predicados `=</2` y `>=/2` requieren que ambos operando (izquierdo y derecho) evalúen a un número (en particular no puede tener variables sin instanciar).

Ya existe un predicado en SWI que puede ser utilizado tanto para chequear pertenencia en un rango como para generar valores dentro de un rango dado: [`between/3`](https://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/doc_for?object=between/3)

```
x(N,R) :-
  between(1, N, R).
```

Alternativamente puedes usar [CLP(FD)](https://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/man?section=clpfd-predicate-index):

```
:- use_module(library(clpfd)).
x(N, R):-
  R #=< N, R #>= 1,
  label([R]).
```